# Mirroring-like functionality in SQL Express via replication?

Tags: sql-server, replication, sql-server-express, mirroring

We have 2 SQL Express (2005) servers. 
As you probably know, database mirroring is not enabled in the Express editions, but replication is.
Would it be possible to enable replication between both servers to have some kind of mirroring-like functionality?! 
What would be the possible drawbacks if it is possible at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will not be able to produce what you are looking to achieve using only the express Edition of SQL Server

I can confirm that SQL Server Express can only operate as a subscriber and not a publisher.

See the following MSDN reference, particularly the comments under the sub-heading "Publisher"

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165654(SQL.90).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I dont think SQL Express can be a Replication provider, only a subscriber.